# How to set the Zone of a Go time value when knowing the UTC time and time offset?

Tags: go, timezone

I have an UTC time and a time offset in seconds, and need to return the corresponding Go time value.

It is trivial to instantiate the UTC time value by using the time.Unix() function. But to set the Zone, I need to determine the time.Location.

How can I find the time.Location when knowing the UTC time and time offset ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Without an actual entry to lookup in the time zone database, you can't know the true location for the time. If you want to work with just an offset, you can create a fixed location using [`time.FixedZone`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#FixedZone)

```
edt := time.FixedZone("EDT", -60*60*4)
t, _ := time.ParseInLocation("02 Jan 06 15:04", "15 Sep 17 14:55", edt)
fmt.Println(t)

// 2017-09-15 14:55:00 -0400 EDT
```

You can opt to specify a non-existent zone name, or none at all, as long as the output format you use doesn't require one.

```
minus4 := time.FixedZone("", -60*60*4)
t, _ = time.ParseInLocation("02 Jan 06 15:04", "15 Sep 17 14:55", minus4)
fmt.Println(t.Format(time.RFC3339))

// 2017-09-15T14:55:00-04:00
```

Comment: Good suggestion. The problem is that I don't know the time zone name.

Comment: Specifically, a true time zone entry includes details like observance and schedule for daylight savings/summer time, which is not included in a simple UTC offset.

Comment: @chmike: If you don't know the actual time zone name, then you can only guess, or leave it out entirely. I only used "EDT" as an example, it's not a real time zone.

Comment: @Adrian You are right. An UTC time with an offset could match multiple locations if their time offset are the same during some period. There would be an ambiguity. The FixedZone is thus the best solution so that it is still possible to produce ISO 8601 time format or equivalent without zone name.

Comment: The zone name is only used in old time representation (RFC822, Unix time). More recent time representation use only the time offset.

Comment: @chmike: yes, as long as you're choosing a suitable output format, just leave the name field bank (the time package will use the offset for the name if the format asks for it)

Comment: @chmike and JimB: "Etc/GMT-14" through "Etc/GMT+12" are perfectly valid timezones and hence according "locations" should be available.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg what are these ? Time zone names ? The time offset I have is in minutes. There are many locations that don't have a time offset rounded to hours.

Comment: @chmike Those are timezone names in the IANA TZ database. If you need a more precise approach, using RFC3339 timestamps might be the handiest option.